# Variation of Hubble constant in cosmological timescales

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, physical-constants

Although the Hubble constant appears to be a constant, it is not really a constant.

Is the Hubble constant decreasing over cosmological timescales?

Comment: @BobBee You're thinking of the cosmological constant. The Hubble parameter has a complicated behaviour over time, viz. the Friedmann equations.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136056/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18301/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69050/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Hubble parameter change with the age of the universe?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136056/)

Comment: @J.G.Thank you for pointing that out. Definitely thought it was about the cosmological constant.  And definitely and totally agreee the Hubble parameter is a significant functon of time.  Deleting my previous comment, I absolutely misread the question.