# Is an $R \sim O(T^2)$ acceleration of expansion of the Universe possible based on data?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, space-expansion, cosmological-constant

We currently assume based on observations that the expansion of the Universe is accelerating. Now this can mean a lot of things, but for some reason it is always described as an exponential acceleration, probably because it immediately clicks with the cosmological constant of GR and this fits with the currently popular models (like the ΛCDM). Is it (hypothetically) possible that the acceleration is *below* exponential? So the "scale factor" is just some polynomial of time, even just $T^2$ (this is the lowest power that gives a positive acceleration)? Could this be fitting the data?

Comment: I understand that [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/141168/the-3rd-derivative-of-the-size-of-the-universe?rq=1) ponders about the same thing, but it would be good if someone would share a more fresh opinion.