# Why is light affected by gravity even though it is massless?

Tags: gravity, visible-light, photons, mass-energy

Why is light affected by gravity even though it is massless?

Comment: Because they carry energy.

Comment: possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34352, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158481, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2229, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107930

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can gravity affect light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130552/)

Answer (score 1):

The important clarification is that objects with **energy** is affected by space time curvature which is **gravity**. This obviously includes massive objects as mass is equivalent to energy.

Also, notice the equation $E=mc^2$ is only a special case of the original relativistic energy-momentum relation equation when the object has zero momentum, that is - its velocity is zero: $$E^2=(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2$$

Where $p$ is momentum so when a non zero rest mass object is at rest, $p=0$ and it simplifies to $E=mc^2$.

Now, for photons/light they have **zero rest mass**($m=0$) *but* they do have a value for **momentum**. So thus then the energy of a photon from the equation becomes:
$$E=pc$$
So then the correct relation comes like:
$$E=hf=pc$$
$$p=\frac{hf}{c}$$
Thus,
So finally we can say that the photon can have energy even though it does not have mass, because it has **momentum**. Thus it is in reality that objects with **energy** are influenced by space-time curvature. So since light has energy(so it has momentum) so it's effected by spacetime curvature.

Comment: Momentum is defined as "the quantity of motion of a moving body, measured as a product of its mass and velocity." If light has no mass, then any velocity it has doesn't mean it has 0 momentum?