# Where does the energy from expanded light go?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, space-expansion

The universe is expanding and light traveling through it also expands. Light with longer wavelengths have less energy so light is losing energy as the universe expands. Where does this energy go? Or what am I missing here?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but Googling "where does the energy in redshifted photons go?" will give you relevant results. I imagine you tried Googling "expanded light" and I would expect that would get  you nowhere since that is not the terminology.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Photons in expanding space: how is energy conserved?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13577/photons-in-expanding-space-how-is-energy-conserved) and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/444443/how-can-the-red-shift-due-to-hubble-flow-be-consistent-with-the-law-of-conservat and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7060/redshifting-of-light-and-the-expansion-of-the-universe