# My question is about big bang theory

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion, big-bang

Oh sorry my English is weak I am only 11 years old but I love physics. My question was is related to the work of Maxwell and Einstein -- nothing can go faster than light and if we give an object enough energy to move at the speed of light it can attain the velocity of light but if we supply more energy to tend it to move faster than light it will never move faster then light but in spite of that, it will gain mass. So if every big bang happened and the particles exploded highest they will move at the speed of light so the total length it can cover is only 3m along all axis in one nano sec but big bang explains that after 1 nano sec after the big bang the universe expanded as large as it is today so plz clarify my question and sorry if there is any mistake in grammar.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you are asking? "the next dimension after calculating 3m in 1ns"does not really mean anything. Light travels 0.33m in 1 ns.

Comment: Apart from the wrong calculation, there is a conceptual problem here. We don't know what the actual size of the universe is. We only know what the causally connected size of our local part of the universe is. What we are seeing of the universe today, that would not have been large, but that doesn't allow us to say anything about the absolute size or shape of the universe, either now or back then.

Comment: The light-speed-limit does not apply to *space* itself, so the universe can expand as quickly as it wants.

Comment: [The Big Bang didn't happen at a point](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/).

Comment: Hi Faisal, it is a fairly good question for an 11 year old. Your basic misunderstanding comes from not realizing that the velocity of light is a limit, and for massive particles if it is ever reached it means that the mass in E=mc^2 will be infinite, and nothing can be bigger than infinity.  The limit will be approached but never reached. The history of the Big Bang  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang is in terms of the expansion of space time .

Comment: It is not an explosion at a point in space  and particle mass that has spread out.   see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnENgtCdObo&feature=youtu.be .The space itself is expanding in three dimensions pulling the mass with it. The balloon analogy is useful, it is in two dimensions on the sphere. the Big Bang is in three dimensions .  Space expansion is not limited by the velocity of light.

Comment: Also in the figure you will see that it took billions of years for the present universe.

Comment: A related question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60519/

Comment: Oh i got it thankyou anna you are right i was confused that if it is impossible to go faster than light then how could we write  c² in e=mc² thanks once again for your answer

Comment: Only 11 years old and you have an account? Interesting.