# Hubble's Law paradigm

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, space-expansion, faster-than-light

I have seen a [video](http://www.khanacademy.org/science/cosmology-and-astronomy/universe-scale-topic/big-bang-expansion-topic/v/hubble-s-law) on Khan Academy about the Hubble's law.

And my question is if the "Hubble's constant" increases by (70.6 km/sec)/parsec then could we reach such a velocity that it gets faster even than light? What If the edge of the observable universe is expanding on such a speed that has surpassed the speed of light. Is a question that has been bothering me all day long. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can space expand with unlimited speed?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60519/)

Comment: The first two answers to this question should cover it: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60519/

Comment: For a quick preview, yes it expands faster than light beyond a certain distance.