# What will happen if one reach the boundary of the Universe?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion

My question is what and how the boundary of the universe should be like. I mean what if someone tried to pass through it. Since the universe is not expanding at the speed of light therefore we can surely catch it. What if you try to push through it. What will happen after all if someone reaches the edge of the Universe. Clearly there must be matter near it what if they move towards the boundary. And above all will laws of physics will be same there?

Comment: What boundary? Also, [space can expand faster than light](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60519/50583).

Comment: The universe has a fixed size. And I  said that it does not expand faster than light to justify that we can touch the boundary before it move farther.

Comment: Please cite where you have read that the universe has a fixed size. At this point there is really no doubt that it is expanding.

Comment: There is no boundary. There is a horizon though. The term "horizon" is most appropriate: just like the horizon observed on earth, it moves along with the observer and can not be reached.

Comment: In a sense we are all at the time boundary, going forward in time.

Comment: By fixed size I mean it is not infinite at any certain moment.

Comment: It has a certain end and I am asking what if we reach that end. Also the earth's horizon can not be reached as the earth is round and we can not reach the horizon. The Universe must end somewhere.

Comment: Are you aware of the balloon analogue of the universe? We are like ants on the surface of a balloon. they will never find an end of their two dimensional universe, and we cannot find an end in our three dimensional universe

Comment: The current thinking is that the universe is most likely flat and infinite, so that even the ant-o- a-balloon doesn't seem to be a good analogy.

Comment: @freecharly: But it is a good example of how something can be finite yet unbounded - thus demonstrating that Prashant's syllogism is false.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - In this regard you are, of course, right!

Answer (score 1):

> Since the universe is not expanding at the speed of light therefore we can surely catch it.

There is no law that says spacetime,  as it is not a "thing", cannot expand at any speed, even beyond the speed of light. ACuriousMind refers to this in the comments above and the link included: [Space Expansion And The Speed Of Light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60519/can-space-expand-with-unlimited-speed).

> What will happen after all if someone reaches the edge of the Universe?

By definition,  the universe is all there is, so there can't be a boundary in the normal sense of a boundary wall, as if there is something beyond the "wall", if should still be part of the universe.
One way that might get around this is to say, or find out preferably, if the universe has positive curvature. I am wary of giving 3 D analogies, such as an ant running around the curve of a soccer ball,  but there, I've just done it......damn

> Clearly there must be matter near it what if they move towards the boundary. And above all will laws of physics will be same there?

Why should there be matter near it? Anyway, this is a moot point  if you accept my argument that a boundary cannot exist between two parts of the one universe.

We don't have any reason to suppose the laws of physics will be different anywhere ( except in black holes), but we don't have any proof that they are the same as here. We don't know.