# What is the co-moving distance to a point, at which the late-time acceleration of the universe began?

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, universe, dark-energy, observable-universe

First of all sorry for my English - it is not my native language.

According to the [following wonderful diagram](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60519/can-space-expand-with-unlimited-speed/63780#63780) made by [Pulsar](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/24142/pulsar),

the late-time acceleration of the universe began at $t_{acc}=$ 7.7 billion years (indicated by the horizontal black dashed line).

[image: Graph of the evolution of the expanding universe made by Pulsar]

**I want to know a co-moving distance ($\mathbf R$) of an object or region that is closest to us, among astronomical objects or regions being accelerated by the late-time acceleration of the universe**.

I think that the value ($\mathbf R$) corresponds to the x-coordinate of the intersection of the horizontal black dashed line and the orange thick line, in the above diagram; that is, **about 9 Gly**.

**Q1) Is this interpretation correct?**

Meanwhile, in order to more precisely indicate $t_{acc}=$ 7.7 billion years, it seem that it is necessary to slightly move up the horizontal black dashed line, as depicted by the red dotted line in the following diagram.

[image: Modified Diagram]
If so, it seem that $\mathbf R$ should be about 8 Gly, which is indicated by the blue dotted line.

**Q2) Which of 8 or 9 Gly is the right value of $\mathbf R$?**

In addition, the Pulsar's diagram was made based on the condition that the Hubble parameter is 67.3 (km/s)/Mpc. Does anyone have a diagram made under the condition of 70 (km/s)/Mpc? Or, does anyone know what the value of $\mathbf R$ under the condition of 70 (km/s)/Mpc is?

Comment: Every galaxy is accelerating, in the sense that if you specify any two galaxies A and B, the proper distance $r_{AB}$ will have $\ddot{r}_{AB}\ne0$. On small scales, this will be dominated by the peculiar motion, which is basically Newtonian, and can have either sign. As you go to larger scales, the accelerations will tend to be systematically positive, due to dark energy. When you talk about a galaxy that's accelerating, do you mean one for which its proper distance from *our own* galaxy has $\ddot{r}>0$? The closest such will be one whose acceleration is mainly peculiar, not cosmological.

Comment: @BenCrowell Right! I found that I did not express the meaning of acceleration clearly. So, I revised the post. The acceleration mentioned in the above post means the late-time acceleration of the universe (so-called, caused by dark energy).

Comment: The turning point when the deceleration turns into acceleration occurs when d²a/dt²=0, see http://yukterez.net/lcdm/hubble.differential.2.png which would be 7.6 billion years after the big bang, using the cosmological parameters from the Planck mission Ωm=0.315, Ωλ=0.685

Comment: @Yukterez Thank you for the image showing the informative mathematica code. However, what I want to know is the co-moving distance of the turning point. If you know the distance, I would appreciate it if you let me know the value.

Comment: That happened everywhere, not only at a special distance. However the distance associated with the light travel travel time of 7.6 Gyr is 3.5 Glyr at emission, which is a comoving distance of 29 Glyr, see http://redshift.yukterez.net