# Can the expansion of the Universe be faster than the speed of light?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, big-bang, faster-than-light

I am reading the textbook "The Cosmic Perspective 8th ed.", in the chapter describing the earliest moments of the Big Bang, one of the sentences is

> [...] a sudden and dramatic expansion of the universe the size of that we call **inflation**. In a mere $10^{-36}$ second, pieces of the universe the size of atomic nucleus may have grown the size of our solar system.

It seems to me that such an expansion is much faster than the speed of light. Is the expansion of the universe not restrained by the speed of light?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can space expand with unlimited speed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60519/)

Comment: My favourite reading on this topic: https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0310808 See in particular the graphic on page 7.