# What implications does special relativity have on the accelerating expansion of the universe?

Tags: special-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, speed-of-light, space-expansion

Under special relativity we have the Lorentz factor:
$$
\gamma = \sqrt{\frac{1}{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}
$$
Which essentially mathematically describes how the relative speeds between objects can never surpass the speed of light, but only tend towards it, even for two photons travelling in opposite directions away from each other.

Applying this to the accelerating expansion of the universe, this must mean that although distant galaxies are (in our galaxy's frame of reference) moving away from the Milky Way at accelerating velocities, their accelerations must eventually decrease as they tend towards the speed of light.

Is this a valid interpretation of the physics? What (if any) implications does this have for the rate of creation of new space and the evolution of the universe?

Comment: To be clear, all of the effects of special relativity do also happen in general relativity.

Comment: But adding to Charlie, general relativity subsumes special relativity (it is what happens locally in the theory) so many results look rather different. An accelerating expansion of the universe can produce *observable* galaxies moving away faster than the speed of light, something that does not happen in pure special relativity!

Comment: Is this not a fundamental violation of physics? Nothing should be observably faster than the speed of light in a vacuum.

Comment: [Can space expand with unlimited speed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60519/37364)

Comment: Also about inflation... [When the universe expanded faster than light](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHGb9fKUBrI)

Comment: *accelerations must eventually decrease as they tend towards the speed of light.* That’s not true. In SR an object can have *constant* proper acceleration *forever* and never exceed the speed of light. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_motion_(relativity)).

Comment: You cannot use SR to describe the motion of the distant galaxies. https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0310808v2 See Section $3.1$