# How many orders of magnitude faster was the speed of cosmic inflation compared to the speed of light $c$?

Tags: cosmology, speed-of-light, space-expansion, faster-than-light, cosmological-inflation

Inflation guy Andrei Linde says it like this:

> … "In that microscopic time interval ($10^{-35}$ sec), the size of the cosmos grew dramatically, going from a diameter of $10^{-33}$ centimeters — the Planck length, that is the smallest size endowed with physical meaning — to one of tens of orders of magnitude greater than the diameter of the current observable Universe."

Which translates to $10^{27}/10^{-35}=10^{62} \text{m/s} =10^{54} c$.

Thus, a cosmic inflation speed **54 orders of magnitude faster** than the speed of light $c$!

This is said not to be in conflict with SR since spacetime itself can expand faster than $c$ although matter and light cannot transverse inside spacetime faster than $c$.

So, if the fabric of spacetime can deform faster than light then can it also transfer some kind of information faster than light?

Comment: See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/504948/180843) to "Can space expand with unlimited speed?". It's a coordinate effect, nothing is moving faster than light in a relativistic sense (and "space expanding" is just a coordinate choice anyway).

Comment: How did you get a numerator of $10^{27}$ from what Linde wrote?

Comment: "The radius of the observable universe is therefore estimated to be about 46.5 billion light-years" https://tinyurl.com/5c4dn69r That calculates in the order of 8.8 x $10^{26}$ m in diameter.