Can a light signal from Earth reach a galaxy outside the Hubble Horizon?
Is this video on the FLRW metric (timestamp 29:00 minutes) mistaken in its claim that a light signal from Earth cannot catch up with a galaxy outside the Hubble horizon, due to the horizon receding at the speed of light?
It would seem to me, that if we can see the particle horizon (otherwise known as the observable horizon) which is outside the Hubble horizon, then by the cosmological principle, observers on the particle horizon can also seen Earth which means they are observing light rays that came from Earth.
Another counter argument would be this: If we had 1000 galaxies (G1 to G1000) all lined up from Earth to the Hubble horizon and a galaxy outside the Hubble Horizon (G1001) then by the time a light signal gets to G1000, to an observer on G1000 the local speed of light is c and there is nothing to stop the signal continuing from G1000 to G1001 because by the cosmological principle (the universe is homogenous and isotropic and any galaxy looks like it is at the centre of the expansion) the physics at G1000 is no different to that at G1.

For more info & diagrams related to expansion see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60519/123208 & links therein.

There are various "horizons" in cosmology, and it is important to distinguish between them. This Wikipedia article describes several such cosmological horizons, two of which are the Hubble horizon and the particle horizon.
The distance to the Hubble horizon (the Hubble radius) is given in terms of the speed of light $c$ and the Hubble parameter $H(t)$ by
$\displaystyle r(t) = \frac c {H(t)}$
Since we believe $H(t)$ is decreasing with time, this means that the Hubble radius is increasing with time. An object that is beyond our Hubble horizon now is therefore not necessarily beyond our Hubble horizon in the future. Whether or not it remains beyond our Hubble horizon for all future times depends on what assumptions we make about the expansion of the universe. As the Wikipedia article says:

It is a common misconception that light from the Hubble radius can never reach us. In models assuming decreasing $H$ with time ... while particles on the Hubble radius recede from us with the speed of light, the Hubble radius gets larger over time, so light emitted towards us from a particle on the Hubble radius will be inside the Hubble radius some time later. In such models, only light emitted from the cosmic event horizon or further will never reach us in a finite amount of time.


Here are some more reasons a light signal from Earth must be able to reach and pass the Hubble Horizon.
The total velocity of a photon is given by its peculiar velocity and its recession velocity as seen from Earth: $$v_{\text{tot}} = v_{\text{rec}} +v_{\text{pec}}.$$
The peculiar velocity of a photon is the velocity measured by a local observer who is at rest with the bulk flow. To comply with SR and GR this is always measured to be $c$, so the total velocity of a photon moving away from Earth is $$v_{\text{tot}} = v_{\text{rec}} + c.$$

In the diagram above, the red worldline represents the Hubble Boundary and is where the expansion flow is equal to the speed of light. The green worldlines are those of galaxies outside the Hubble boundary that are receding at greater than the speed of light. The blue worldline is the trajectory of an  outgoing photon. At event $\text{R}$ the total speed of the photon relative to Earth is $1.9c$ because the recession velocity is $0.9c$ at that location. It has no problem catching up with the boundary at event $\text{S}$, where the total velocity of the photon relative to Earth is now $2c$ and it easily continues on to catch up with the next Hubble flow object at $\text{T}$ which is 'only' moving at $1.1c$ relative to Earth. The dashed green line is the worldline of an galaxy receding at $9c$ and visually it looks like our photon could never catch up with that worldline, but if you zoom out using the scroll wheel of your mouse using the GeoGebra construction for that diagram you will see event $\text{N}$ where the photon overtakes that $9c$ object, despite the galaxies' extreme velocity relative to Earth. In fact the photon can catch up with any object with a finite constant velocity relative to us.
The above diagram assumes the scale factor as a function of time scales as per $a(t) = t$ which is a simple idealised model that assumes a empty universe with no gravity slowing down the expansion. In reality the scale factor is closer to $a(t) + t^{2/3}$ and the recession velocities curve slightly inwards as they gradually slow down due to gravity. This does not prevent the photon catching up with the boundary.
The FLWR metric for an expanding Universe taking only radial motion into account is $$ c^2 \mathrm{d}\tau^2 = c^2 \mathrm{d}t^2 - a^2(t) \ \mathrm{d}X^2$$ assuming a flat universe (and $k=0$) which is close to what our Universe appears to be. $X$ is a so called comoving coordinate. This is the distance from the Earth to a given galaxy at the current time. Despite the fact the galaxy is receding, the convention is that $X$ is deemed to be constant and independent of time. This is a bit weird but it is the convention used by cosmologists. $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}X}{\mathrm{d}t}$ is the motion of a particle relative to that fixed distance. Rearranging the metric we get: $$ a(t) \frac{\mathrm{d}X}{\mathrm{d}t} = \sqrt{c^2 - c^2 \frac{\mathrm{d}\tau^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}}.$$
For a photon we set $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\tau}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0$ and obtain the peculiar velocity of a photon in coordinates where the observer acknowledges the universe is expanding as $$ a(t)\frac{\mathrm{d}X}{\mathrm{d}t} = c.$$
The 'real' local peculiar velocity of a photon is always $c$ for any non zero value of $a(t)$ as it should be.
In coordinates where the observer considers distance $X$ to be fixed despite the fact the distance is really increasing over time in an expanding universe, the peculiar velocity of light is given by: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}X}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{c}{a(t)}.$$
In these coordinates the peculiar velocity of light appears to be slowing down over time. This is an artifact of treating the expanding distance as a constant value.
If a photon can travel the distance $X$ in the comoving coordinates where $X$ is considered fixed, it can also travel the distance $X'$, which is the corresponding distance where the distance is expanding over time. We can find out how far a photon can travel in a given time by integrating the last equation:
$$\Delta X = \int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{c}{a(t)} \ \mathrm{d}t$$
which is infinite for any reasonable value of $a(t)$, e.g.  $a(t) = t^{2/3}$ for a matter dominated universe or $a(t) = t$ for an empty universe. In other words, if a galaxy is at infinite distance from us right now, a photon sent from Earth right now will eventually arrive at that galaxy. If the Hubble boundary is at finite distance from us right now, a photon leaving now will have no trouble catching up with the expanding boundary in a finite amount of time, in any reasonable cosmological model. It works both ways. We can eventually see light from any object in the universe, no matter how far away it is now, and no matter how fast it is receding. This is for any fixed value of $a(t)$, even e.g. $a(t) = t^2$, so that recession velocities are proportional to time squared. In effect there is no event horizon if $a(t)$ is constant. However, if $a(t)$ is increasing over time there may be an event horizon.
In any reasonable model of the universe, arguments that an object has to be overtaken by the Hubble boundary in order for us to see them, are not correct. Just to be clear, there are objects outside the Hubble boundary that we do not yet see. Not enough time has elapsed since the beginning of the Universe for us to see them now. These objects are outside what is known as the particle horizon or the current 'visible universe'.
This diagram that might convince you if you are not already:

We are at $\text{G}$ and the blue curve is a cross section our past light cone. We can see everything that is on the surface of our past light cone. We see light now, that was emitted at event $\text{H}$ which was on the Hubble horizon. We also see light from event $\text{F}$ which was emitted by the object with the purple worldline which was moving at $4c$ relative to us. We are seeing light right now, from a superluminal object that was outside the Hubble horizon at the time it was emitted and which is still outside the Hubble horizon right now. Clearly there is no need for the light to be emitted when the object is inside the Hubble horizon.
As pointed out by @Yukterez, in a matter dominated universe, worldlines of individual galaxies curve inwards due to gravity. In such a case, the purple worldline would eventually fall inside the Hubble boundary (which is not a physical boundary and so is not slowed down by gravity). However, we can see the purple galaxy long before it falls inside the Hubble boundary. This is better illustrated in the new chart below:

This is the chart updated to show a more realistic matter dominated universe with $a(t) = 2/3$, together with the parametric equation used to plot the blue worldline on the ingoing photon. The factor of $1.6$ that appears several times in the equation is the distance away the galaxy was at the time the light was emitted at one unit of time. It shows the outward flow of galaxies slowing down over time due to gravity and ending up inside the Hubble radius (red worldline). The photon emitted by the galaxy at event $\text{F}$ while it was outside the horizon still arrives at us at event $\text{G}$.

KDP wrote: "Objects that are outside the Hubble horizon that are rest with the Hubble flow stay outside the Hubble horizon." - that is the case since the dark energy dominated era when the expansion went accelerated (d²a/dt²>0), but in the radiation and matter dominated eras things that were outside the Hubbleradius came inside it, see the lower part of the comoving spacetime diagram where the Hubbleradius is blue and the worldlines dashed gray.

@Yukterez I think I get what you are getting at. While I was mostly  using a hypothetical empty universe, in a matter dominated universe worldlines of matter curve inwards and are overtaken by a boundary (not a particular galaxy) moving outwards at c. In light of your comment, I will delete that paragraph.

The details of the answer depend on the specific scenario, so let us assume for simplicity that the horizon is always at a constant distance. The chain of galaxies that your are imagining, assuming they are not bounded, will separate from each other at some speed (because of the universe expansion), the farther away the fastest. G1000 might be close to the cosmological horizon now, so you can see in the far future what is going on there today, but it will soon move beyond the horizon, so it will also become unreachable in the future. Regarding your initial signal from G1, it will reach G1000 in the very far future. At that time both G1000 and G1001 will have moved very far apart, so that now G1001 will be outside the cosmological horizon of G1000 (and also G1000 from G1's horizon), so G1000 will not be able to send the signal to G1001.
