# What is the relationship between Cosmic Time and Scale Factor (or Redshift)?

Tags: cosmology, time, space-expansion

I was looking at the answer to this question: [The difference between comoving and proper distances in defining the observable universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/400358/the-difference-between-comoving-and-proper-distances-in-defining-the-observable) and wanted to reproduce the chart in order to better understand the relationship between the Hubble Sphere and the Particle Horizon, but I'm stuck with a very basic problem:

[image]

How do you map Cosmic Time (left axis) to Scale Factor (right axis).  Obviously it was done for this chart, but I can't find a formula anywhere.

**EDIT:** I found this formula on the Wiki pages.  This is specifically the formula that I'm trying to solve:
$$\eta(t)=\int_0^t \frac{dt\prime}{a(t\prime)}$$
Where do I get the formula for $a(t\prime)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Cosmic Time***

Let us denote the age of the universe as $t$. By using $\frac{da}{dt} = \dot{a}$ we can write

$$t = \int_{t_e}^{t_0}dt =\int_{a(t_e)}^{a(t_o)}\frac{da}{\dot{a}}~~~~(1)$$ But instead of working in $da$ we can convert it to $dz$. We know that $$1 + z = a^{-1}$$

hence

$$dz = -a^{-2}da$$ or $$da = -a^2dz = -(1+z)^{-2}dz ~~~~(2)$$

and we have

$$\frac{\dot{a}}{a} = H_0 E(z)~~~~(3)$$

Where

$$E(z) = \sqrt{\Omega_{r,0}(1+z)^4 + \Omega_{m,0}(1+z)^3 + \Omega_{\Lambda,0} + \Omega_{\kappa}(1+z)^2}$$

Let us put $(2)$ and $(3)$ into $(1)$

$$t = \int_{a(t_e)}^{a(t_o)}\frac{da}{\dot{a}} = \int_z^0 \frac{-(1+z)^{-2}dz}{aH_0E(z)}$$ Which is equal to

$$t = \frac{1}{H_0}\int_0^z \frac{dz}{(1+z)E(z)}$$

Let us do the calculation for the current age of the universe,

$$t_{uni} = \frac{1}{H_0}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dz}{(1+z)\sqrt{\Omega_{r,0}(1+z)^4 + \Omega_{m,0}(1+z)^3 + \Omega_{\Lambda,0} + \Omega_{\kappa}(1+z)^2}}$$

For $\Omega_{r,0} = 0$, $\Omega_{m,0} = 0.31$, $\Omega_{\Lambda,0} = 0.69$ and $\Omega_{\kappa} = 1 - \Omega_0 = 0$,

$$t_{uni} = \frac{1}{H_0}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dz}{(1+z)\sqrt{0.3(1+z)^3 + 0.7}}$$

If we use the https://www.integral-calculator.com and do the numeric calculation we obtain

$$ \int_0^{\infty}\frac{dz}{(1+z)\sqrt{0.3(1+z)^3 + 0.7}} = 0.9641$$

For $H_0 = 68km/s/Mpc$

$$t_{uni} =  0.9641 \times H_0^{-1}= 0.9641 \times 14.39~\text{Gyr} = 13.8733 ~\text{Gyr}$$

***Conformal Time***

In this case from the FLRW metric we can write,

$$ds^2 = -c^2dt^2 + a^2dr^2$$ 
for light $ds = 0$ Thus we have,

$$c^2dt^2 = a^2dr^2$$ or

$$r= c\int_{t_0}^{t_e}\frac{dt}{a(t)}$$

Conformal time represents the time it takes for the light to travel distance $r$. Mathematically

$$\eta = \frac{r}{c}$$

$$\eta = \int_{t_e}^{t_o}\frac{dt}{a(t)}$$

But you can write this equation in terms of z to make the calculations easier.

So we know that $$1 + z = a(t)^{-1}$$

hence

$$\frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{dz} {da} \frac{da} {dt}$$
$$\frac{dz}{dt} = -\frac{1}{a^2} \dot{a}$$
$$dz = -\frac{\dot{a}}{a^2}dt$$

$$\eta = \int_{t_e}^{t_o}\frac{dt}{a(t)} = \int_{z}^{0}\frac{-dza^2 / \dot{a} }{a}$$

Thus

$$\eta = \int_{0}^{z}\frac{dza}{\dot{a}} $$

And by using (3) you can write

$$\eta = \frac{1}{H_0}\int_{0}^{z}\frac{dz}{E(z)}$$

When you use the above equation to calculate the conformal time since the begining of the universe you need to write,

$$\eta = \frac{1}{H_0}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dz}{E(z)}$$

When you use the integral calculator site and do the above integral you will get

$$ \eta = 3.2 \times 1/H_0 = 3.2 \times 14.38Gyr = 46.016 Gyr$$

In summary the age of the universe for a given $z$ can be calculated by

$$t = \frac{1}{H_0}\int_0^z \frac{dz}{(1+z)E(z)}$$

and the conformal time

$$\eta = \frac{1}{H_0}\int_{0}^{z}\frac{dz}{E(z)}$$

*These integrals cannot be done by hand (in general). Either you need to write a computer program or more simply just you can use the site that I mentioned and select the numerical calculation box.*

*I did all my calculations for a given $z$ value but I only did this to show you the difference between $t$ (cosmic time) and $\eta$(conformal time). For a given $a$ you can easily find the corresponding $z$ by using $z=a^{-1}-1$ and then you can calculate $\eta$ or $t_0$.*

**Edit**: To answer your other question. There's not a direct equation but you can find a way to do it. For instance, let us use equation $(3)$

$$\frac{\dot{a}}{a} = H_0 E(z)$$

but in this case, we will write $E(a)$ instead of $E(z)$ which is a simple thing to do. So we have

$$E(a) =\sqrt{\Omega_{r,0}a^{-4} + \Omega_{m,0}a^{-3} + \Omega_{\Lambda,0} + \Omega_{\kappa}a^{-2}}$$

$$\frac{da}{dt} = a H_0 E(a)$$

Now, $a$ goes inside of $E(a)$ as $a^2$. Thus

$$\frac{da}{dt} = H_0 \sqrt{\Omega_{r,0}a^{-2} + \Omega_{m,0}a^{-1} + \Omega_{\Lambda,0}a^2 + \Omega_{\kappa}}$$

so $$t = \frac{1}{H_0} \int_0^a \frac{da}{\sqrt{\Omega_{r,0}a^{-2} + \Omega_{m,0}a^{-1} + \Omega_{\Lambda,0}a^2 + \Omega_{\kappa}}}~~~~(4)$$

So we have a function of $t(a)$ however for some values you can take the inverse of this function (It makes problem for the closed universe models). For instance you can plot $t$ vs $a$ ($t(a)$) and then reverse the axis to get $a$ vs $t$ ($a(t)$). This is the general case.

If you are asking for our universe you can make some approximations and then find the function. For example, you can [look at this site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model#Cosmic_expansion_history). But it's only an approximation and works for only some $\Omega$ parameters with a given time interval.

Either you have to make an approximation to equation (4) for each case and then take the inverse, or you have to plot $t(a)$ and from there by chaning the axis you can find $a(t)$. I am not sure if there's another way to do it.

Comment: Is this formula giving cosmic time or conformal time?

Comment: It gives the cosmic time

Comment: Try it for $a(t_e) = 0.8$ you ll see that t is close to $10Gyr$. Conformal time has a similar equation indeed but its written in terms of $z$ $$ \eta = -\frac{1}{H_0}\int_{\infty}^{0}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{\Omega_r(1+z)^4 + \Omega_m(1+z)^3 + \Omega_{\Lambda}}}$$ There is a quite difference.. if you want to know where the cosmic time equation comes from I can show you the derivation

Comment: I don't mean to sound ungrateful - this is a really useful formula - but I really want to go in the other direction. That is, looking at the chart in the original post, I want a linear axis of time (or conformal time, I can convert) and the less-than-linear scale factor.  My math skills aren't up to the task of solving this integral for $a$.

Comment: @GluonSoup I edited my post maybe this helps

Comment: @GluonSoup Thats just the visual part of it. Its just matching the two values and scaling them in some order. In your original post you wrote an equation about $\eta$. Thats the conformal time not the age of the universe.

Comment: @GluonSoup I made further editions I realized that I made some mistakes

Comment: What is the function $E(z)$ called?

Comment: @GluonSoup I dont think it has a name

Comment: First, thank you for the background material, it was very useful.  Now, to my original question, does a formula exist that allows me to go from cosmic or conformal time ($t$ or $\eta$) to redshift or scale factor?  That is, $f(t)=z$ or $f(\eta)=a$?

Comment: @GluonSoup I answered

Comment: Alright, reversing the axes seems to do the trick.  Not elegant, but the purpose was to get a plot of t vs. a, so it works.  Thanks again for this material, it helped a lot.

Comment: @GluonSoup Indeed not very elegant...As far as I know it is the only way. Your welcome, happy to help :)

Comment: The formula $$r= c\int_{t_0}^{t_e}\frac{dt}{a(t)}$$ is incorrect.  You can't just remove the $c$ term from the integral like that.  It should read $$r= \int_{t_0}^{t_e}\frac{c}{a(t)}dt$$

Comment: @GluonSoup $c$ is a constant. So I can

Comment: Gotcha.  Same result both ways.  You're right.