Observable universe
What does observable universe mean? I saw your graphs in proper and comoving distances. An hypothetical object that emitted light at the Big Bang (after recombination: cosmological time $t=0$ and proper distance close to 0 with respect to our world line) is now at a proper=comoving distance (since now $a=1$) of 46 billion light years away from us (particle horizons). But do we see it now as if it had been 46 billion light years away from us at time $t = 0$? (light cone in comoving distance).

The observable Universe is the (finite) subsection of the Universe that we can see (observe). Is that not a sufficient answer?

(+1) @controlgroup After the big bang, do the front runners who form the outermost expanding sphere feel any gravitational pull of the rest of the slower pack behind them, according to GR? Could they not keep running forever because they are so ahead of everything else?

It’s a common misconception that the Big Bang was everything exploding outwards in a spherical fashion. The Big Bang was just the moment that the distances between points stopped being zero for all points; the Universe is roughly homogenous in all directions.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I’m referring to graphs of this discussion: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/400358/the-difference-between-comoving-and-proper-distances-in-defining-the-observable

Isn't the Wikipedia page clear enough itself?? Seems complete in itself to me.
