# How to compute light travel time from a galaxy that is 'now' emitting to us?

Tags: cosmology

I am trying to replicate the space time plot (the 2nd plot with Proper distance vs Time) as in this thread:[A Cosmological horizon at the Hubble radius?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70339/a-cosmological-horizon-at-the-hubble-radius)

I wrote everything in python using the astropy cosmology package.
Everything went smooth, but I am stuck at plotting the light path on the 'purple path', as per the example in the link. I don't know how to plot the light path for the light emitted by the galaxy at t0 = 0 (now), with the proper distance of aprox 13.8 Glyr, that will reach us a t=49 Gyr.
Here is the code in python:

```
from astropy import units as u
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate as inter
import astropy.constants as cc


# hubble radius

def Hradius(zed):
    c = cc.c
    return (c/cosmo.H(zed)).to(u.Glyr)




#define cosmology

cosmo = Planck18



# Z and time

redshift = np.arange(-0.9,1089,0.1)

redshift_R = redshift[::-1]

time=cosmo.age(redshift)



# trajectory of a galaxy G1 with z=1.48

TrajectoryG1 = [cosmo.scale_factor(i) * cosmo.comoving_distance(1.48737).to(u.Glyr).value for i in redshift]



### Can't make this work

#lightPathG1 = [cosmo.scale_factor(0) * cosmo.comoving_distance(i).to(u.Glyr).value for i in redshiftG1]



# horizons

hubbleRadius = [Hradius(i).value for i in redshift]

hubbleRadiusMirrored = [-Hradius(i).value for i in redshift]

lightPath = [cosmo.scale_factor(i) * cosmo.comoving_distance(i).to(u.Glyr).value for i in redshift]

lightPathMirrored = [cosmo.scale_factor(i) * -cosmo.comoving_distance(i).to(u.Glyr).value for i in redshift]





term1 = [cosmo.scale_factor(i) for i in redshift]

term2 = [cosmo.comoving_distance(i).to(u.Glyr).value for i in redshift_R]

term3 = [-cosmo.comoving_distance(i).to(u.Glyr).value for i in redshift_R]

particleHorizon = [term1*term2 for i in range(len(redshift))]

particleHorizonMirrored = [term1*term3 for i in range(len(redshift))]



#plot

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.plot(time,hubbleRadius, 'g-', label = 'Hubble radius')

ax1.plot(time,hubbleRadiusMirrored, 'g-')

ax1.plot(time,lightPath, 'y-', label = 'Light path')

ax1.plot(time,lightPathMirrored, 'y-')

ax1.plot(time,particleHorizon, 'b-', label = 'Particle horizon')

ax1.plot(time,particleHorizonMirrored, 'b-')



ax1.plot(time,TrajectoryG1, 'k',linestyle='-.', label = 'G1 trajectory')

#ax1.plot(timeG1,lightPathG1, color = 'orange')



ax1.set_ylim(ymin=-50, ymax=50)

ax1.axvline(x=13.7,color='grey',linestyle='--',alpha=0.5)

ax1.axhline(y=0,color='grey',linestyle='--',alpha=0.5)



ax1.fill_between(np.append(time.value, time[::-1].value), np.append(hubbleRadius, hubbleRadiusMirrored[::-1]), color = 'green', alpha = 0.1)



ax1.invert_xaxis()

ax1.legend()

ax1.set_xlabel('Time (Gyr)')

ax1.set_ylabel('Proper distance (Glyr)')
```

The resulting plot:

[image: space-time]

With @benrg help, the plot works as expected:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have neither defined nor imported `redshiftG1`, so it's no wonder `lightPathG1`'s declaration doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cosmo.comoving_distance` gives you the $(z,r(z))$ coordinates of a null geodesic that passes through $(0,0)$. By homogeneity, $(z,r_0+r(z))$ is also a null geodesic for any $r_0$. You want $r_0\, a(z{=}0) \approx 13.8\text{ Glyr}$.