# Light cone shape

Tags: cosmology, distance

Looking at figures such as on the following page:
[Is the cosmic horizon related to the Big Bang event?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41058/is-the-cosmic-horizon-related-to-the-big-bang-event/41068)

I am a bit confused about the shape of the light cone. In the top diagram (proper distance) it makes sense that the light cone is not a straight line, since the total velocity takes into account the recession velocity as the universe expands. However, in the middle diagram (comoving coordinates) where the expansion is filtered out, I don't understand why the past light cone is not straight lines. We don't have expansion and we are also assuming flat space (ΛCDM model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using comoving coordinates gets rid of the expansion of the coordinate distance between two objects that are each at rest relative to the Hubble flow. It doesn't get rid of the expansion in general, for objects that are moving relative to the Hubble flow. Light rays are moving.

The middle diagram has as its axes the comoving coordinate $\chi$ and the clock time $t$ of an observer at rest relative to the Hubble flow. Suppose that someone in galaxy A sends a radio signal to cosmologically distant galaxy B, then B immediately replies and sends a signal back. A receives the reply after some round-trip time $\Delta t$. Now say they do it again, so we have $\Delta t_1$, $\Delta t_2$, and so on. These times have to get longer and longer. But if the light cones looked like the standard 45-degree lines on this $\chi$-$t$ graph, then the $\Delta t$'s would all be the same.

Usually when we talk about shapes in GR, we mean intrinsic shapes. A geodesic such as the world-line of a light ray is intrinsically straight. (It gets a little more complicated when you talk about the shape of the entire light cone, since it's possible in some cases to rule a curved surface with straight lines.)